# Get ActiveStorage blob as a blob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm building a Rails app that will allow users to access certain uploaded files directly in the browser but at a different URL to the actual file. This is so that the files can be protected by forcing login.

So for example you might access a file at: `domain.com/file/19371da`

In the past I have done this by using CarrierWave and then doing `to_blob` on the file itself and then sending it back using `send_data` and using data stored about the file in the database:

```
send_data @file.file.to_blob, stream: false, filename: @file.name, type: @file.mime_type, disposition: 'inline'
```

However when using the new Active Storage as a potential replacement for CarrierWave I've hit a snag at getting the actual file itself as blob to pass to the `send_data` method.

e.g.

```
send_data @file.file.to_blob, stream: false, filename: @file.file.blob.filename, type: @user.file.blob.content_type, disposition: 'inline'
```

It gives an error `undefined method 'to_blob' for #<ActiveStorage::Attached::One:0x007f8f23ca2718>`.

How can I get the actual file as a blob in Active Storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to do this you have to use the `download` method:

e.g.

```
send_data @file.file.download, filename: @file.file.blob.filename, type: @user.file.blob.content_type, disposition: 'inline'
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5e8c79a6fafb8d7a84c272b3c9a0474a0d01b471/activestorage/lib/active_storage/attached/one.rb#L67) for `ActiveStorage::Attached::One` it looks like there is a `blob` method which means you should just be able to call:

```
@file.file.blob
```

Comment: Hmm doesn't work for me. When I inspect the blob method though it's just the hash of the values against the record stored in the database in `active_storage_blobs` and not the actual blob of the file itself like if I had called `to_blob`.

Comment: You can access the the attachment values at `@file.file.attachment`. So it doesn't look like `.blob` is the correct method for accessing the file as a blob as that method just returns the blob object.

Comment: See the response below - use the download method

Answer (score 1):

I think you have resolved your problem from now. 
If not, you can go across `has_one_attached` and [`has_many_attached` documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Attached/Macros.html#method-i-has_many_attached) to know how to get Blob from relations – using `<my_relation>_blob` shortcut.

To get [a link for direct-download](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Blob.html#method-i-service_url_for_direct_upload), you can do this :

```
 @my_model.file_blob.service_url_for_direct_upload expires_in: 30.minutes
```

Dependent on how secure you want your system to be, you could just send this short-living url to your signed-in users, it won't expose the original file path (not 100% sure about that).